# I have a search page functionality in Dynamics 365. It takes values in a form and sends to a Javascript file. I want those values in a C# file too

Tags: javascript, c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

As mentioned in title, I have a search page functionality in Dynamics 365. It takes some values in a form and when clicking on Search button, a Javascript file runs and retrieves those values. I want those values in a C# file too. What is a possible way to achieve it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a custom action, then execute that action from JS using web api. Now you can register a plugin on that custom action message name.

While executing action, You can pass the parameter to action and same can be consumed in the c# plugin.

[Read more](https://carldesouza.com/creating-a-custom-action-and-calling-it-from-web-api-in-dynamics-365-power-apps/)